# Is it normal that an analog voltmeter has about 7K ohm input impedance?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, multimeter, kirchhoffs-laws, voltmeter

I have bought 10V 6c2 DC analog voltmeter, and I have tested it with a regulated DC power supply and it measured pretty accurately different voltages, however when I tried measuring the voltages in a simple circuit like KVL (30V DC source, 3 resistors: 10K, 22K, 33K) I got a quite high deviation from what I should have, for example I got only about 0.5V across the 10K resistor instead 1.5V.

I measured the input resistance of the voltmeter and I found it to be 7K!, shouldn't be with mega ohm's range?

[image]

Comment: What does the datasheet say?  It's not necessarily high impedance like a good DMM, it may have been designed to measure a low impedance source.

Comment: I can't find anything regarding that !

Comment: Like John D said - it's just a dumd, passive meter, with no electronics to provide a high input impedance.  What your measuring is probably just the DC resistance of the coil.

Comment: Class 1.5 Perhaps same kind of infos in this https://www.laalouelectric.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/SFIM-2015.pdf

Comment: If you want a "high" impedance, just use a good op-amp "voltage follower"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would it be MΩ?  It is an analog meter.

[image]

Specifically (from image):

DC, Permanent Magnet Moving Coil (D'Arsonval Meter Movement), 1.5% error on full-scale reading, vertical mounting, difficult to see test voltage.

Source: [Symbols in Analog Measuring Meter & meaning of it](http://www.marineeto.we.bs/2020/05/08/symbols-in-analog-measuring-meter-meaning-of-it/)

[image]

Source: [D’Arsonval Movement](https://instrumentationtools.com/darsonval-movement/)

Meter is based upon D'Arsonval Moving Coil Meter Movement.  Meter works on motor principle, where current flowing through coil moves needle proportional to current.  The coil has resistance and current which will cause full-scale deflection.  Typically, 1mA.  Full scale 10V should cause full-scale deflection current.  1mA at 500Ω = 0.5V.

[image]

Source: [D’Arsonval Movement Meter](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-8/voltmeter-design/)

To extend range, a resistor is placed in series with the meter movement.  This resistor drops most of the voltage only allowing <0.5V across the meter movement.
This series resistor converts a meter which measures current into a voltmeter.

If you measure voltages for a circuit with small ohms (<1kΩ), your answers will be closer to theoretical values.

Corruption occurs when the resistance of the meter is less than or close to resistance being measured.  Or when meter current is close to circuit current.  It's because the meter steals the current to make it work.  Your measured 7kΩ is less than 10kΩ (smallest), so all readings would be off.

From meter image: 6C2  GB/T7676

From: [6L2 dial instrument](http://www.zone.zj.cn/6L2/6L2-6C2.html) [& 6C2]

> Summary:

> This series of meters is suitable for various electric quantity control equipment and scientific research departments to test metering instruments, power stations, power grids and other power system distribution board to measure the power consumption, can work normally in damp and hot environment. The instrument performance indicators meet the requirements of GB/T7676.1 ~ 9 standard.

This is a panel meter meant to monitor up to a 10V rail for industrial applications and ships.  Not what you are looking for.  It will read source voltages (1.5% error).

Answer (score 4):

That is an industrial panel meter. Typically we want a sensitivity in the 1mA F.S. range for robustness and so they behave well with vibration and shock. It has a moving-coil DC movement, and either taut band or jeweled suspension.

With 7K and 10V full-scale voltage, the full scale current is 1.4mA which is fine. To get "megaohm" input resistance with a sensible movement design would require an internal amplifier and a separate power supply. Which you can easily add on the outside if it is required (eg. 12V supply and op-amp voltage follower).

Portable analog multimeters use more sensitive meters (as much as practical) so they don't disturb the measured voltage as much. A typical spec is 25,000\$\Omega\$/V or 40uA F.S.

Note: Most of the resistance you see will be a low tempco series resistor so you can add some appropriate ordinary series resistance to get a 30V or whatever scale without undue worry about the Cu tempco. This becomes a concern when you are trying to measure very low voltages (tens of mV), but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an analog electro-mechanical voltmeter without any solid state amplifier, how should it be possible to make megaohms input resistance with a wirewound coil and a resistor in series?

You need at least some microampere current through the coil to move the needle of a simple small robust meter like this. 50 µA is a typical sensitivity for portable multimeters, this would result in 200 kiloohm input resistance. But non portable robust panel mount meters need much more current than 50 µA.

Comment: Thank you Uwe, is there a simple solution around this?

Comment: 40 to 50 µA is a typical range for portable multimeters. These robust ones may need 10 times that, or more. @Shamooooot, it is not clear the solution around what problem are you trying to achieve. You asked if this low resistance is expected for this voltmeter, and it is.

Comment: The meter is mechanical with a low mechanical resistance. Instead, use an electronic meter with 10 Million ohms of input resistance.